# What does the directory-name: '~MntWIM' on my Windows 7 / C:\ drive mean?

Tags: windows-7

This '~MntWIM' on my Windows 7 / C:\ drive, is sized: 694 MB (728.418.589 bytes) on harddrive.
It contains 3 subdirectories. 
1st = Program Files, containg zero volume
2nd = Users, containing zero volume
3rd = Windows, containing 693 MB (726.823.197 bytes) on harddrive

It all looks a bit useless to me, so question is: Is it safe to delete the lot?
Or does it have an important function there?

Hoping for an answer from which I could lern something.
B.R.
JP

Comment: The folder appears to be related to the [Acronis Bootable Media Builder](https://forum.acronis.com/forum/44228), and it's probably a leftover. Have you ever used any Acronis tool?

Comment: Rename it first. If nothing complains about it, then it's safe to delete.

Answer (score 4):

Was your system upgraded from a previous version of windows via a downloadable installer?

- `Mnt` is a common abbreviation for "mount" (Filesystems, such as from a CD/DVD/HardDrive are "mounted" by the operating system to use them; this includes disk images)
- `WIM` is the [Windows Imaging Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format), which would also indicate a disk image
- `694 MB` is about the size of a CD-ROM disk image (These are usually around 690-705MB)

I highly suspect this was where a windows disk image was downloaded to and mounted from for a piece of Microsoft software that you installed or upgraded (possibly the OS), or another tool was mounting and manipulating windows disk images, but this is all guesswork.

Given the `~` at the front, I would expect it to be temporary, and if it's still there after a reboot, you can probably delete it or relocate it.